# geo location datatype is not creating from spring data elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am performing the index from spring data using bulkrequest.

For the location, I am sending a List of Geopoints.

```
jsonMap.put(LOCATION,List<GeoPoint>);
```

After executing in elastic search it is not creating as a type of Geopoint. Mapping is as follows.

```
"location": {
    "properties": {
      "lat": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "lon": {
        "type": "float"
      }
    }
  }
```

Because of this I am not able do geoLocation sort. 
Any idea what went wrong?

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: What is your entity class definition? With which methods do you save your data ? How is the index mappings created? Which versions do you use?

Comment: I manged to fix it.GeoPoint won't support auto mapping,I have added mapping support and then indexing.

Answer (score 0):

As Geopoint data type won't support auto mapping,We have to do the mapping manually and then indexing

Comment: When you let Spring Data Elasticsearch write the mappings for your index, `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint` is correctly mapped to `geo_point`.